# how can i change the workflow name link in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I would like to change the custom action "Workflow" not the workflow name.
Just the link to the workflow when you create one from sharepoint designer.I'm using 2010.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I changed it via Sharepoint Designer custom actions.
Go to sharepoint designer and open up the list look right below and you will see  custom actions..Click New
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I changed it via Sharepoint Designer custom actions.
Go to sharepoint designer and open up the list look right below and you will see  custom actions..Click New
Cheers

Comment: Actually it didn't change the default one it just replaces it with a new one.
Any ideas